# Sum of multiple variables (with many entries for each currency) in a pandas DataFrame()

Tags: python

Let me make an example: Let's assume I have a list of sales in different countries with different currencies in a pandas DataFrame(). I would like to get a list with the sum of sales in each currency's sales.

What I have done is to use set() to get a list of the currencies, and then loop through each currency and take the sum of the sales, and then append it to a data frame. However, this seems very inefficient and I am trying to find a better way.

Eventually, I would loop through different data sets which would mean I have a double loop. Loops are not very efficient. I would appreciate any help on this. I am new to python, and no - this is not for school.

Comment: what is the structure of your dataFrame? how can you tell currencies apart? are they in different columns?

Comment: Since this is for work, I can't share a picture. But it's basically a column with name "CCY" and then many rows with different currencies (like GBP, USD, EUR, ...)  and a second column with it's corresponding value, let's call it "SALES" (which I would like to sum for each currency).

Comment: use groupby and sum. `frame.groupby('CCY')['SALES'].sum()`